# IPtables filters vanishes - Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I have used IPtables commands to block some IP`s, but now when I use #iptables -L to see the current filters, nothing is in there in my Ubuntu iptables firewall.

I use the command like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP
iptables-save > /etc/network/iptables
```

It adds and works for a while but I guess after a reboot it vanishes.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

in your network interface file under your man WAN facing nic add:

```
 pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Can you please explain better? I am noob when it comes to linux.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/537595/what-could-be-the-cause-of-machines-on-the-lan-not-having-internet-access-via-th <-- He is doing something different but I stole the iptables line from his /etc/network/interfaces file.

Comment: So you mean I have to insert the command you gave after this?
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

Comment: Was I right about the conclusion?

Comment: should work. Give it a try.